# how to make a .bat file "activate" when the PC sleeps

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way that I can make a batch program begin when I put my computer to sleep?
I would like to disable a USB port when I put my computer to sleep. Is this possible if so, how would I go a out doing so?

Comment: Maybe you need an additional tool to capture going to sleep event, maybe C#? This one will trigger what you need.

Comment: You can use task scheduler for the even trigger, now if you know how to disable the port form command line then your a go see: http://superuser.com/questions/325450/how-to-schedule-a-task-for-sleep-hibernate By the way the topic is better suited for superuser

Comment: Use `devcon.exe` which is a device manager command line tool from Microsoft.

You can use a batch file to disable the USB port and then put the machine to sleep from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

As this has not been marked as closed I am assuming the author has not been able to piece together the answer from the comments. This answer is derived from those comment hints and gives the detail that perhaps the questioner requires....

If you search for information on using the task scheduler to trigger on the sleep event  you get to [this page at Microsoft](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a5f9d579-00c7-49fd-9bf4-a13ef1a01c93/task-scheduler-on-laptop-lid-close?forum=w7itproui), which contains the following:

1. Input “Task Scheduler” in search box and press Enter
2. Click “Create task…” on the  Task Scheduler---Action
3. Go to Triggers,   create new triggers
4. On “Begin the task”, select “On an event”
5. Select Log to “system” , set “Source” to “Kernel-Power” , Event ID
   is “42” and click “Ok”
6. Go to “Actions” and create a new actions
7. You can select “Start a program”, “Send an e-mail” and “Display a
   message” on action as you need.
8. Save the task scheduler
9. On conditions tab, check the box “Wake the computer to run this task”. Click OK.

The information about using devcon.exe is on [this microsoft page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) which shows the following command does the trick:

```
devcon disable *MSLOOP
```

You can either make a batch-file calling devcon, or have the task scheduler call devcon directly with the appropriate arguments.

Is that enough detail to explain the solution?